# How to receive data from template file using ajax in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have some checkbox fields in template file.All the checked values should be sent to views file.I used ajax to prevent page reloading.How to send these data to backend(views.py)?

My template file,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myform").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var category = [];
        $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(i){
            category[i] = $(this).val();
            });

        $.ajax({
            url :'/welcome_user/',  
            type : "GET", 
            data : { 
                category_name : category,
            },
            success : function() {
                console.log('Success'); 
            },
            error : function() {
                console.log('Failure'); 
            }
        });
    })
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myform">
        <p>Categories</p>
        {% for i in My_Cat %}
            <input id="category_id" name="category_name" type="checkbox" 
            value="{{i.category}}" >{{i.category}}<br>
        {% endfor %}
        <input id="submit" type="button" value="Go"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

views.py,

```
def welcome_user(request): 
    categories = Add_cat.objects.all()   

    if 'category_name' not  in request.GET:
        my_products = Add_prod.objects.all()
        context = { 
                "My_Cat":categories,
                "products":my_products    
        }
        if request.is_ajax():
            print "Hello world"
            print request.GET.get('category_name') #getting undefined


    if 'category_name'  in request.GET:
        filter_category = request.GET.getlist('category_name')
        my_products = Add_prod.objects.filter(cat__category__in = filter_category)

        context = { 
                "My_Cat":categories,
                "products":my_products    
        }      
    return render(request,"welcome-user.html",context)
```

I am not getting any error.If I check two checkboxes it is not recognizing it.This is what I see in my console.

`"GET /welcome_user/?category_name%5B%5D=Economics&category_name%5B%5D=Kids HTTP/1.1" 200 5743`

Answer (score 0):

Try not to mix things. If you want to submit something by ajax, don't use `submit` input.

Use:

```
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Go"/>
```

instead of:

```
<input type="submit" value="Go"/>
```

and then in you JS:

`$("#submit").click(function(event) {
    ...
});`

**Update**

Reading everything again, I see there are many misunderstandings here. I would recommend you to have two functions, one for the view and other for the ajax request. I'm also doubting whether you really wanted to use ajax, in which case you should start with a [tutorial](https://www.google.es/#q=tutorial%20ajax%20in%20django), or a normal submition.

Comment: Do I need to change anything in views file?

Comment: In the tutorial they are using json for storing and sending data. Is json compulsory in views file if I want to use ajax?